# Why should ViewModel route actions to Controller when using the MVCVM pattern?

Tags: design, design-patterns, mvc, object-oriented-design, mvvm

When reading examples across the Internet (including the MSDN reference) I have found that code examples are all doing the following type of thing:

```
public class FooViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public FooViewModel(FooController controller) {
        Controller = controller;
    }
    protected FooController Controller { get; private set; }

    public void PerformSuperAction() {
        // This just routes action to controller...
        Controller.SuperAction();
    }

    ...
}
```

and then for the view:

```
public class FooView : BaseView {
    ...

    private void OnSuperButtonClicked() {
        ViewModel.PerformSuperAction();
    }
}
```

Why do we not just do the following?

```
public class FooView : BaseView {
    ...

    private void OnSuperButtonClicked() {
        ViewModel.Controller.SuperAction();

        // or, even just use a shortcut property:
        Controller.SuperAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find the answer to this question helpful.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254005/in-mvc-why-cant-a-model-create-a-view

Answer (score 2):

**Consider the model being just data**. It doesn't make choices, and it doesn't know how to render.

- A product can be a model.
- A list of products can be a model.
- A bundle containing the list of products, the cart and the information about the current user is a model.

The last model from the list corresponds to the *data* you need to render the page, but it shouldn't know how to render itself, because it's not the task of the model.

In order to render it, a *view* is used, given that the controller may pick different views depending on the context. It will use for example a view to render data to an ordinary guest visitor, a different view for an authenticated user, and a third view if the user is an administrator. Same data, different modes of displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this a blend of two basic MVCs (this assumes you know the basic MVC).

First, deeper MVC pair is:

- M = model
- C = controller
- V = view model

Second, upper MVC pair is:

- M = view model
- C = collapsed / minimal / interspersed (`OnSuperButtonClicked` is part of it)
- V = view.

With this separation, of course view from one triad cannot access model, nor the controller, from other triad.